# How to click on the basis of style attribute in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I want to click on element which appears like a button on webpage using `style` attribute of `div` tag.

But I am not able to do so. I referred stack overflow but with the help of that its returning blank element . I don't want any text. I want that it should be clicked and the list appears and I want to select one item from that list. So how to do that?

Below is my code :

```
<div style="width: auto; height: 386px;" class="QvGraph">
<img src=" " style="width: 710px; height: 386px; cursor: crosshair; visibility: visible; display: block;"></img>
<div style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 588px; height: 18px; width: 27px;" class="Qv_Hotspot"></div>
<div style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 3px; height: 18px; width: 18px;" class="Qv_Hotspot"></div></div>
</div>
```

I have tried this below code, but it didn't get work for me.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class ='Qv_HotSpot']")).getAttribute("cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 588px; height: 18px; width: 27px;");
```

I am badly stuck here .Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this below code.

If you want to click on `<div>` tag `style` attribute use below code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Qv_Hotspot'][@style='cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 588px; height: 18px; width: 27px;']")).click();
```

**Explanation of xpath:**- Use `class` and `style` attribute of `<div>` tag.

Comment: Thank you @jainish but it clicks on the image which I don't want. I want to click on the other div below image. I edited your code but it doesn't work driver.findElement(By
    .xpath("//div[@class='Qv_HotSpot']/div[@style='cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 588px; height: 18px; width: 27px']"))
    .click();

Comment: Now is it for you as you expected? Can you explain me why you were modifying my `xpath`? Please replace my code with your code. Then only it gets work for you.

Comment: Yes it solved my problem .can you help me for clicking on the basis of title attribute .

Comment: I accepted it jainish. can you help me for title or do I need to post another question ?

Comment: Post `separate` question with some proper details.:)

Comment: I had to insert Thread.sleep(5000) before your mentioned answer then only it works .Can you explain me what's the significance of this thread here ?

Comment: It will stop the execution of your code for `5 mils-seconds.` Usually this will help when your code is interacting with ajax or when you click on button then re-load the page, that time this will work better.

Comment: You mean that it will load data first and then it will execute the below code ? then why it isn't needed in the case of other statements ?

Comment: Yes, First load the data and then after your driver will able to find the web-element. You should use this statement when your web-element may interrupt by loading.